# How do I clear the first two lines of the screen by using the curses library?

Tags: unix, curses

How do I clear the first two lines of the screen by using the curses library? I see that there is a `deleteln()` command, however it only clears the line under the cursor.

Also, a second question, does the command `clear()` clear the whole screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`deleteln()` deletes the line and moves the rest of the text up. `clrtoeol()` clears to the end of the current line.

You need to use `int move(int y, int x)` to position the cursor at the start of each of the 2 top lines and then call `clrtoeol()`.

`clear()` clears the whole window

Answer (score 1):

[parkydr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1071623/parkydr) Said: "`clrtoeol()` clears to the end of the current line."

That's almost correct. `clrtoeol()` clears to the end of the current line from you cursor. So if your cursor isn't at the beginning of the line then it won't clear the entire line.

Here is an example:

```
int y, x;            // to store where you are
getyx(stdscr, y, x); // save current pos
move(0, 0);          // go to the beginning of the first line
clrtoeol();          // clear the line
move(1, 0);          // go to the beginning of the second line
clrtoeol();          // clear the line
move(y, x);          // move back to where you were
```